# install ubuntu on a hardware AES encrypted flash drive

Tags: system-installation, security, encryption, usb-drive, usb-creator

I couldn't find the answer to my question after hours of search. I hope someone can help me out.

I would like to install ubuntu on a flash drive.
I followed to standard instructions for installing the latest ubuntu alternate i386 on a flash drive. However when going through the installation procedure I got stuck at the detection of drives. It can't see my flash drive. And probably I know why... because it's a hardware AES encrypted flashdrive so the USB stick will only be visible and unlocekd after onboard password verification. However this onboard password verification does not show up. How do I fix this problem?

Got a Integral Courier Dual FIPS 197 Encrypted USB 3.0

Thanks for the help!

Comment: hmmm perhaps this problem is unfixable...
Could it be it is impossible to put any OS on a hardware encrypted usb drive?